# Magento 2: I am not aware about Magento optimization. Can you please share the steps for this?

Tags: magento2, optimization, speedoptimization

I am not aware about Magento optimization. Can you please share the steps for this? How to compete with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Switch your website to **production** mode
> 2. **Minify** your HTML, CSS and js files.
> 3. **Merge** your CSS and JS files.
> 4. **Optimize** your images.
> 5. Enable **Gzip** Compression.
> 6. Ensure if Magento **Full Page Cache** is enabled. Can install and configure varnish to speed up the site
> 7. Do **Advanced Javascript Bundling** following this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html as it will reduce total page size as well keeping the number of requests low
> 8. Use the **profiler** to check files consuming more time. Check and ensure to load them in lesser time.
>
>    php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html
>
>    php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable csvfile
> 9. Consider Using **Google Page Speed Module** in your server where you can configure the optimization to speed up the page as well as
>    increasing your google page speed score significantly. To see if this
>    can solve all your problems
>    https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/
> 10. Enable Flat Categories and Products

Comment: Explained well. +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

The best and easy way to speed up the magneto website is page cache. But beside page cache, you can do the following to improve server response.

1. Inspect every installed 3rd-party extension, and disable useless extensions on your website
2. Choose the fastest hosting you can afford
3. Turn Production Mode On
4. Never Use JS Bundling
   [image]
5. Enable CSS/JS Minification
   [image]
6. Last and most importantly, enable profiler and check all the files (.phtml) and events, check which are taking more time to execute. And remember even 0.5 sec for a file or event is also huge time for a single file/event.

Answer (score 2):

7 Tips to Speed up Magento 2

> 1 Inspect every 3rd-party extension installed
>
> 2 Choose the fastest hosting possible
>
> 3 Make sure Full Page Cache is on
>
> 4 Make sure Production Mode is on
>
> 5 Never use JS bundling
>
> 6 Enable CSS/JS minification
>
> 7 Use Built-in Cache, Skip Varnish

For more detail, please visit https://servebolt.com/articles/speed-up-magento-2-in-7-easy-steps/